# Which one is faster NVL or COALESCE in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a use case , where I have a choice to apply `NVL` or `COALESCE`  .
ex: `COALESCE(col_1,'alternate_string')`

```
NVL(col_1,'alternate_string')
```

I know about `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NUll` , but tell me how will I adapt it to this query :
`DELETE FROM TABLE_1 T1 USING TABLE_2 T2 WHERE T1.col_1 = T2.col1 t1.col2 = t2.col2`  and so on . ..... Should I be using Cases for that ? 
How will handle for boolean types.
I want to know which one runs faster in terms of execution time in AWS Redshift ?

Comment: The answer is NA = `Not Applicable`. Faster in *what query*? If you use that in a WHERE clause, both are horrendously slow as both will prevent the use of indexes. If you use that in a `SELECT`, it doesn't matter because a query's time is taken by reading and filtering the data. A simple null replacement is trivial compared to that

Comment: So why are you asking? What is the *real* problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , I am deleting records from one table using another table putting where condition and we know that null=null gives false .So i was doing this , but now i think i will move to  Intersection.

Comment: You're doing it wrong then. The proper way to compare NULLs in SQL is to use `IS NULL`  or `IS NOT NULL`. What you do ignores indexes and forces the query to scan the entire table, convert all values and only then filter those that need deleting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , I know about IS NULL and IS NOT NUll , but tell me how will I adapt it to this query :
DELETE FROM TABLE_1  T1 USING TABLE_2 T2
WHERE  T1.col_1 = T2.col1
t1.col2 = t2.col2
and so on .
.....
Should I be using Cases for that ?

Comment: Edit the question and add the query there, explaining what you actually want to match. If you want to match null values on both tables, you have to use `t1.col1 is null and t2.col2 is null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same:

> [COALESCE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COALESCE.html)
>
> **Synonym** of the NVL expression.

> [NVL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html)
>
> **An NVL expression is identical to a COALESCE expression**